# prototype vars not being overwritten by constructor

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to allow for default settings to be overwritten by the init function but for some reason the it's only using the local settings can anyone please explain why and how I can fix this.

```
var obj = (function() {
  var settings = {
    height : 10,
    width : 20
  };

  function init(settings) {
    this.settings = settings
    setObj()
  }

  function setObj() {
    if (settings.height == 0) {
      console.log('good height')
    } else {
      console.log('bad height')
    }
  }
  return {
    init : init,
  }
})()

var settings = {
    height : 0,
    width : 20
  };
obj.init(settings);
```

Comment: The title is a bit misleading, or at least I don't see in what way prototype is involved

Comment: settings=a where a is passed init is part of a function (the anonymous), therefore this is window

Answer (score 1):

**instead of var use this.settings**

```
var obj = (function() {
  this.settings = {
    height : 10,
    width : 20
  };

  function init(settings) {
    this.settings = settings
    setObj()
  }

  function setObj() {
    if (settings.height == 0) {
      console.log('good height')
    } else {
      console.log('bad height')
    }
  }
  return {
    init : init,
  }
})()

var settings = {
    height : 0,
    width : 20
  };
obj.init(settings);
```

Comment: Also there should be: `if (this.settings.height == 0) {`

Comment: @jukben no need of mentioning this.settings.height as this.settings = settings sets the newsettings when called

Answer (score 0):

The init function is a closure here, even after IIFE executes , init has reference to local variable. So first it checks whether height property of settings object is available locally and grabs the value. But when we use this keyword is used it refers to settings of init function which has the reference to global settings object. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
  var obj = (function() {
  var settings = {
    height : 10,
    width : 20
  };

  function init(settings) {
    this.settings = settings;

    setObj();
  }

  function setObj() {
    if (this.settings.height == 0) {  // use this.settings here. The code works fine.
      console.log('good height')
    } else {
      console.log('bad height')
    }
  }
  return {
    init : init,
  }
})();

var settings = {
    height : 0,
    width : 20
  };


obj.init(settings);
```

Comment: ok so this works but not as expected. it doesn't default to the `var settings` declared at the top of the obj.

Comment: Ok got it. Then a different approach may be needed. I will check later.

Answer (score 0):

I am uncertain as to what you are trying to do, however your question is a great example to help people understand modules and the [revealing module pattern.](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/)

At present when you execute the IIFE the only value it returns to your `obj` variable/Module is an anonymous object with a method which is `init`.

```
return {  // <-- anonymous object returned with all its properties available!
    init : init 
}
```

So the methods bound to that returned object are now available to the module's namespace i.e. `obj`. Everything else is private i.e. `var settings (object), the setObj, (function object)`

Think what might be confusing is this part:

```
function init(settings) {
    this.settings = settings
    setObj()
}
```

When you call `init` this will add a *new* property to obj Module. That is because when you invoke:

```
obj.init(settings);
```

The `this`keyword points to the returned object which was assigned to the obj namespace/Module.

To prove it after invoking the IFFE but **before** invoking `init`on your Module, run:

```
console.dir(obj);
```

> Calling console.dir(object) will log an interactive listing of an
>   object's properties, like > a miniature version of the DOM tab

Essentially you'll get all the properties on obj. At this point it's only init.

So to reiterate, your `init` will not overwrite the `settings` variable, the one in the IIFE assigned to `obj`, that one is inaccessible (unless you use a *public method* to update it). Your `init` adds a property to the object returned by the IIFE.

I added a function to your Module called `checkSettings` and changed your `init` function. I created `checkSettings` so you could see the `settings` obj before you run init and after, essentially so you could see the changes first hand. And my `init` just overwrites the properties if the names match.

```
var obj = (function() {

  var settings = {
      height : 10,
      width : 20
  };

  function init(objProps) {
      for (var p in objProps) {
          if(settings.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
              settings[p] = objProps[p];
          }
      }
      setObj()
   }

  function checkSettings(){
     console.log('The following properties and values are on settings object');     

     for(var p in settings) {
        if(settings.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
          console.log(p + ' ' + settings[p]); 
        }
     }
  }

  function setObj() {
    if (settings.height == 0) {
      console.log('good height')
    } else {
      console.log('bad height')
    }
  }
  return {
    init : init,
    checkSettings : checkSettings
  }
})()
```

Hope this was helpful!